# Why do my textures look different in texture paint mode and object mode?

Tags: texture-painting

As you can see in the attached image below, my textures in object mode (top one) and texture paint mode (bottom one) look different. When in object mode it looks blury, which is not what i want. I will export it to a game engine later, so i dont want it to be blury. Why is it doing this and how can i change it ?

[image]

Comment: What does your texture look like in an external image editor? What does it look like in render view? What are your viewport settings for texture size and mipmap, etc?

Comment: I’m not sure about external image editor. For rendering I use Eevee and just render straight from the viewport. When I created the image for the texture the image size I set was 2048x2048. I’m not sure about the viewport setting you are talking about. Is there a way to increase or decrease viewport quality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly you can turn up the aliasing and filter settings in the Viewport in Preferences like I did here, maybe that will help some.[image]